# Merging and sorting two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

"threads" with the columns ID, forumID, title, content, unixtime

"comments" with the columns ID, threadID, content, unixtime

I would like to do a mysql query which sorts all the rows within these two tables based on their unixtime, but also not showing the same "threadID" twice.

The following query will merge the two tables and sort them, but I cant remove duplicates of the threads. I've tried with some GROUP BY and DISTINCT, but with no luck.

```
(SELECT unixtime, ID, threadID FROM comments)
UNION
(SELECT unixtime, ID, forumID FROM threads)
ORDER BY unixtime DESC
```

Its for showing of the frontpage of a forum, therefor it would make no sense to let the same thread appear more than once.

EDIT: I want to show both the newest comments and the newest threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT unixtime, ID, type, type_id
FROM (( SELECT unixtime, ID, 'comment' AS type, threadID, forumID
        FROM (  SELECT unixtime, ID, threadID
                FROM comments
                ORDER BY unixtime DESC) AS h
        GROUP BY threadID)
        UNION ALL
      ( SELECT unixtime, ID, 'thread', ID, forumID
        FROM threads)
        ORDER BY unixtime DESC) AS h2
GROUP BY threadID
ORDER BY unixtime DESC
```

I changed some stuff. I asume you want to know if it's a forum or thread id?

Comment: This almost works! The only problem is that the same thread will apear once from the "threads" table and once from the "comments" table. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: It works!
Although I just had to add `ORDER BY unixtime DESC` at the bottom.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution if you don't have keys to join:

```
   Select DISTINCT tbl.unixtime from
    (
    (SELECT unixtime, ID, threadID FROM comments)
    UNION
    (SELECT unixtime, ID, forumID FROM threads)
    ORDER BY unixtime DESC))
    As tbl
```

Comment: I need more than the unixtime, so I've tried:

`Select DISTINCT tbl.unixtime, tbl.ID, tbl.tID from
(
(SELECT unixtime, ID, threadID as tID FROM comments)
UNION
(SELECT unixtime, ID, forumID as tID FROM threads)
ORDER BY unixtime DESC LIMIT 0, 100
) as tbl`

But theres still duplicates :(

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get only unique threadID

```
(SELECT forumID, ID, unixtime FROM threads)
UNION
(SELECT distinct(threadID), ID, max(unixtime) FROM comments GROUPBY threadID)
ORDER BY unixtime DESC
```

Comment: This almost works!
The only problem is that the same thread will apear once from the "threads" and table and once from the "comments" table.
Any way to avoid this?

Comment: you want only one thread of a forum and one comment of that thread..
m i right??

Comment: I only want the thread to be shown one time. Robins solution above works perfectly!